# can't find openssl/evp.h when I compile openssl_aes.c with gcc

Tags: openssl

OK,I have install openssl-1.0.1e and I want to complier an program about AES,like this
http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt

the document prompt what I should input to complier

**gcc -Wall openssl_aes.c -lcrypto**

howerver there is an error:

**openssl_aes.c:13:25: **fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.****

So what should I do？

Comment: you should find openssl/evp.h & put the parent directory of openssl in the include path

Comment: Use -I flag to specify the include path to openssl/evp.h.

Comment: @dbasic hank you~I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate openssl/evp.h to your program. All the header files are copied to a folder which you mentioned in Makefile.

That path must be used by your program.

Use -I option to specify the include path.

```
 gcc -Wall -Ipath_to_openssl_headerfiles openssl_aes.c -lcrypt.
```

Comment: if I do this,there are another error. <br/>                            openssl_aes.c:51:22: error: ‘AES_BLOCK_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: So,I think whether I have configured correctly.Because I also can't complier the example in the document:[Des with openssl](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/04/openssl-des-api.html?output=pdf)

Comment: For AES_BLOCK_SIZE, include appropriate file where it is defined.

Comment: OK,I have solved this problem.For Ubuntu , install libssl-dev.And then I can use -lcrypto.